# Minecraft Bin Folder Not Created--Linux Ubuntu

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have some various mods and such that require something to be placed in the bin folder of Minecraft... but on Linux Ubuntu there is no bin folder. What should I do?

Comment: As of 1.6 there is no bin folder. Are you running 1.6.2? And are these mods and their install instructions actually for 1.6.2?

Comment: I am running 1.6.2. Its Single Player Commands and it says that the WE.jar needs to be placed in the bin. Is their some bin replacement??

Comment: The install instructions are [here on the official thread](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-162-single-player-commands-v49-official-download-spc-noclip/#installinstructions). I think you must be reading the instructions for 1.5. The instructions for 1.6 are above that and don't involve the old bin folder.

Comment: Sorry to say this but... it does include the words... .minecraft/bin in those directions and they are the same ones.

Comment: Oh, I see it there down the list. Just make the folder. SPC and WE must still look there, even if Minecraft no longer does.

Comment: I found a link for this "Magic Launcher" thing and its a lot faster then you'd think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the folder. As of Minecraft 1.6 the actual game no longer uses a bin folder and therefore doesn't create one, but some few mods still use it. Creating it yourself will be no different than if Minecraft created it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uncertain about the basics of modding, I highly recommend 'Magic launcher'.

This applet allows players to mod without fiddling around with META-inf and bin folder/directories and the mods can be turned on and off with the click of a check button.

Inexperienced modders can break thier MC by adding or removing classes without knowing whats going on. Good luck :)